# current location in the textview defined in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I am trying to show the current location in the `textview` that is in `Toolbar`, whenever I get the location, the app crashes. Because it cannot show the location in the `TextView` in the `toolbar`. need help.

here is the code of mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LocationListener {

private TextView address;

private LocationManager locationManager;

private boolean gps;
private double Latitude;
private double Longitude;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    gps = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(!gps){
        showSettingAlert();
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M);
    {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 10);
            return;
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, (LocationListener) this);
        }
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void showSettingAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is off.Do you want to go to the Settings menu?");
    // positive button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Latitude = (location.getLatitude());
    Longitude = (location.getLongitude());

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude,Longitude,1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality().toString();
    String sublocal = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality().toString();
    String addr = sublocal + ", " +cityName;

    address.setText(addr);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

now I am getting the address of my current location, but whenever it tries to show in the `address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);` it shows error and app crashes. Here is the `toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                                                                                                             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:text="Getting Location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**LogCat** is here.

```
12-13 17:03:48.566 30101-30101/com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-13 17:03:48.568 30101-30101/com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1, PID: 30101
                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:159)
                                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:290)
                                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0(LocationManager.java)
                                                                                           at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:235)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
12-13 17:03:54.641 30101-30112/com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1 I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 38
12-13 17:03:54.647 30101-30157/com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1 D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0xaf797000
12-13 17:04:03.404 30101-30101/com.wanderalchemy.wanderalchemydraft1 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30101 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: post your  activity_main.xml and error so we can help you.

Comment: wait I will be giving everything

Comment: @Dharmishtha I am not able to edit the question any more. The question is that the app crashes instead of getting the location. and the logcat shows that there is a null pointer passed. But the same code was working fine just a weeks ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    
address = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
```

Instead of this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
```

**EDIT**

```
List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: still, the problem persists.. the app crashes when the address is loaded

Comment: @BikramNath share your crash log with question

Comment: I think the problem is in the getting the location part. I will check once more. then I will update..

Comment: @BikramNath sure let me know if any query

Comment: @BikramNath just intialize your arraylist like this **`List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList();`**

Comment: the app crashes again

Comment: @BikramNath share your **`Address`** class with quetion

Comment: I am not getting it. I am not using any Address class. also, I want to add that the app was working last week, but now it stopped working. also leave the toolbar part also. I need to show it to a simple textview in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
address = (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
```

Comment: I did not downvote. I do not the ability to downvote actually.

Comment: @BikramNath why are you unselect my ans. This is correct ans.